# Is any jquery method to invoke property panel while loading autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I want to show property panel in autodesk forge viewer while loading itself.
How to do that with client side javascript?

Comment: What you have try so far?  Please share sample code so can get better idea about issue

Comment: Thanks folks, Already got the answer from Bryan.            viewer.getPropertyPanel(true);
viewer.getPropertyPanel().setVisible(true);